# Group count with MongoDB using aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say my MongoDB schema looks like this:

```
{car_id: "...", owner_id: "..."}
```

This is a many-to-many relationship.  For example, the data might look like this:

```
+-----+----------+--------+
| _id | owner_id | car_id |
+-----+----------+--------+
|   1 |        1 |      1 |
|   2 |        1 |      2 |
|   3 |        1 |      3 |
|   4 |        2 |      1 |
|   5 |        2 |      2 |
|   6 |        3 |      4 |
|   7 |        3 |      5 |
|   8 |        3 |      6 |
|   9 |        3 |      7 |
|  10 |        1 |      1 | <-- not unique
+-----+----------+--------+
```

I want to get the number of cars owned by each owner.  In SQL, this might look like:

```
SELECT owner_id, COUNT(*) AS cars_owned
FROM (SELECT owner_id FROM car_owners GROUP BY owner_id, car_id) AS t
GROUP BY owner_id;
```

In this case, the result would look like this:

```
+----------+------------+
| owner_id | cars_owned |
+----------+------------+
|        1 |          3 |
|        2 |          2 |
|        3 |          4 |
+----------+------------+
```

How can I accomplish this same thing using MongoDB using the aggregation framework?

Comment: @JohnnyHK, I don't think me listing the 10 different ways I've tried to accomplish this will help you or anyone else answer this question more effectively, because they didn't work. I have already done some legwork in explaining exactly what I'm trying to do, and the approach I might take in SQL. I have looked up and down the MongoDB documentation, and none of my pipeline aggregation approaches have worked, probably because I'm still new to using the aggregation framework.

Comment: In your schema, does each document just have one car (represented by id) ? In that case, to find the number of cars owned by an owner, aren't you really just looking for how many documents in your collection have that owner_id ? In that case, you could do something like db.foo.find( { owner_id : [owner id here] } ).count() to get the number of documents in your collection with that owner_id.

Comment: It's totally fine that your existing code doesn't work, but by posting it we can see what direction you were taking and what concept you may be missing.

Comment: @Louisa, it's a many-to-many relationship.  There can be many cars and many owners.

Comment: Can there be multiple docs with the same `owner_id`/`car_id` pair?  e.g. two docs where `owner_id = 1` and `car_id = 1`?

Comment: @JohnnyHK, that's a really important question, nice catch.  The answer is yes, there can be duplicates.

Comment: By the way, if the non-uniqueness seems confusing, imagine that this collection contains annual license registration information or some such.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

To accommodate the potential duplicates, you need to use two `$group` operations:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    { $group: {
        _id: { owner_id: '$owner_id', car_id: '$car_id' }
    }},
    { $group: {
        _id: '$_id.owner_id',
        cars_owned: { $sum: 1 }
    }},
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        owner_id: '$_id',
        cars_owned: 1
    }}]
    , function(err, result){
        console.log(result);
    }
);
```

Gives a result with a format of:

```
[ { cars_owned: 2, owner_id: 10 },
  { cars_owned: 1, owner_id: 11 } ]
```

Comment: Great answer.  I was really close.  I had the pipelined 2 groups, but I was supplying a field name to the `$sum` operator instead of a 1.  This solved it.  Thanks!

Comment: How can I limit the output to only those that own more than one car (cars_owned > 1)?

Comment: @IngviGautsson 
 `{$sort : {"cars_owned" : -1}},
 {$limit : 10}`

add after `$project` and before `]`

Comment: oh god, sql is so simpler, bring sql back again!

Answer (score 0):

`$group` is similar to SQL Group by command. In the below example, we're going to aggregate companies on the basis of the year in which they were founded. And calculate the average number of employees for each company.

```
db.companies.aggregate([{
    $group: {
      _id: {
        founded_year: "$founded_year"
      },
      average_number_of_employees: {
        $avg: "$number_of_employees"
      }
    }
  }, {
    $sort: {
      average_number_of_employees: -1
    }
  }
])
```

[image: $avg operator MongoDB]

This aggregation pipeline has 2 stages

1. `$group`
2. `$sort`

Now, fundamental to the `$group` stage is the `_id` field that we specify as the part of the document. That is the value of the `$group` operator itself using a very strict interpretation of the arrogation framework syntax. `_id` is how we define, how we control, how we tune what the group stage uses to organize the documents that it sees.

The below query find the relationships of the people with companies using `$sum` operator:

```
db.companies.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    "relationships.person": {
      $ne: null
    }
  }
}, {
  $project: {
    relationships: 1,
    _id: 0
  }
}, {
  $unwind: "$relationships"
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: "$relationships.person",
    count: {
      $sum: 1
    }
  }
}, {
  $sort: {
    count: -1
  }
}])
```

[image: $sum in MongoDB]

Comment: what happened to these screenshots?