# Mongodb - Group and count

Tags: mongodb

Below is my mongodb structure

```
 [
  {
    "_id": "com.android.angrybirds",
    "rating": [
      {
        "user": "BBE74610BEE1A92784FDB",
        "value": "1"
      },
      {
        "user": "BBE74610BEE1A92784F",
        "value": "5"
      },
      {
        "user": "BBE74610BEE1A9784F",
        "value": "5"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to group and count the unique ratings. I tried to use aggregate, group but it didn't work.

Expected output

```
[
  {
    "_id": "com.avatarrom.angrybirds",
    "rating": [
      {
        "1": 1,
        "5": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you show us your non working aggregation query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @RickyA said, your aggregation query would be interesting. What you need is the *aggregate* function in combination with the *group* operator. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240039/group-count-with-mongodb-using-aggregation-framework) has a nice sample how you can do that.

Comment: That was a very useful link. It followed the same logic and it worked.