# MongoDB (v3) aggregate and count all rows

Tags: mongodb

i need group all users by age and then need count all rows.

```
db.users.aggregate({
    $group : {_id : "$age"}
    }
);
```

I have read MongoDb [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.count/), but don't get how working count and aggregate together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group count with MongoDB using aggregation framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240039/group-count-with-mongodb-using-aggregation-framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group all your grouped data by age together and use aggregational [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) for counting all rows from the grouped data:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $group : { _id : "$age" }
  },
  {  
    $group : {
      _id : null,
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this within a single `group` query:

```
db.users.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$age",count:{$sum:1}}]);
```