# How can query in MongoDB that count number of 2 equal field?

Tags: mongodb, count, nosql, conditional-statements, grouping

I have a collection in MongoDB for my survey results(`name=surveyresults`). I want to have a query that gives me the number of correct answers based on category, for example, category "Bee" number of correct answers 10.
I tried different ways but these are not results that I want. 
I have searched and found this post [Group count with MongoDB using aggregation framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240039/group-count-with-mongodb-using-aggregation-framework) useful but not working for me.

This is part of my data in my `surveyResults` collection :

```
[{"_id":"0eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOjE5LCJpYXQiOjE1MjQwMDgzOTl9.2YvhnXtCD7-fm4B14k10m6NF7xuv7moCTbekVekkbvY","category":"Wasp","photo":"A_wasp_565","description":"","answer":"Bee","__v":0},{"_id":"1eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOjE5LCJpYXQiOjE1MjQwMDgzOTl9.2YvhnXtCD7-fm4B14k10m6NF7xuv7moCTbekVekkbvY","category":"Wasp","photo":"A_Pompilid_wasp_007","description":"","answer":"Wasp","__v":0},{"_id":"2eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOjE5LCJpYXQiOjE1MjQwMDgzOTl9.2YvhnXtCD7-fm4B14k10m6NF7xuv7moCTbekVekkbvY","category":"Wasp","photo":"wasp_248","description":"","answer":"Wasp","__v":0},{"_id":"3eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOjE5LCJpYXQiOjE1MjQwMDgzOTl9.2YvhnXtCD7-fm4B14k10m6NF7xuv7moCTbekVekkbvY","category":"Fly","photo":"A_butterfly_291","description":"kjlkjlkjlk","answer":"Moth/Butterfly","__v":0},
```

I want result like this :

```
[{"category":"Fly","count":3, "correct":1},{"category":"Wasp","count":3, "correct":1},{"category":"Moth/Butterfly","count":4, "correct":2},{"category":"Bee","count":3, "correct":1}]
```

Now I have these two queries but not giving me correct results :

1.

```
SurveyResults.aggregate([
    { $group: {
        _id: { answer: '$answer', category: '$category' }
    }},
    { $group: {
        _id: '$_id.answer',
        answer_correct: { $sum: 1 }
    }},
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        answer: '$_id',
        answer_correct: 1
    }}
]).exec(callback);
```

2.

```
SurveyResults.aggregate([
    {
    $group:{
        _id:"$answer",
        count: { $sum : {$cond : { if: { $eq: ["answer", "$category"]}, then: 1, else: 0} }}
    }
}]).exec(callback);
```

Also, I can have the number of answers based on the category by this query:

```
SurveyResults.aggregate([
    {
    $group:{
        _id:"$answer",
        count: { $sum : 1 }
    }
}]).exec(callback);
```

Results:

```
[{"_id":"Don't know","count":2},{"_id":"Fly","count":3},{"_id":"Wasp","count":3},{"_id":"Moth/Butterfly","count":4},{"_id":"Bee","count":3}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you want:

```
SurveyResults.aggregate([
    $group: {
        _id: "$category",
        "count": { $sum: 1 }, // simply count all questions per category
        "correct": {
            $sum: { // and sum up the correct ones in a field called "correct"
                $cond: [ // ...where "correct ones" means
                    { $eq: [ "$category", "$answer" ] }, // that "category" needs to match "answer"
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: { // this is just to effectively rename the "_id" field into "category" - may or may not be needed
        _id: 0,
        "category": "$_id",
        "count": "$count",
        "correct": "$correct"
    }
}]).exec(callback);
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much @dnickless, exactly what I want